# Widget for IBM Watson conversation chatbot

Tags: chatbot, watson-conversation

Anyone can suggest a javascript widget to be used for Watson conversation chatbot?

It should be simple to implement in any page, can remember user session and `context`, and support RTL interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case would be the easiest to build one on your own - you may check out their GH to see some samples - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple and https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-bot then you can apply your own css/js and just consume their API. As far as I know there no something like generic widget which you can style and just embed in your website.